# Flutter: how to avoid special characters in validator

Tags: validation, dart, flutter, special-characters

I have this validation function:

```
class FormFieldValidator{
  static String validate(String value, String message){
    return (value.isEmpty || (value.contains(**SPECIAL CHARACTERS**))) ? message : null;
  }
}
```

I would like to indicate that doesn't have to contain special characters, but how can I say it?

Comment: You can use regex to check this, you can check is you data contains only alphanumeric or not.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Here is a somewhat more general answer.

## 1. Define the valid characters

Add the characters you want within the `[ ]` square brackets. (You can add a range of characters by using a `-` dash.):

```
// alphanumeric
static final  validCharacters = RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$');
```

The regex above matches upper and lowercase letters and numbers. If you need other characters you can add them. For example, the next regex also matches `&`, `%`, and `=`.

```
// alphanumeric and &%=
static final validCharacters = RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9&%=]+$');
```

#### Escaping characters

Certain characters have special meaning in a regex and need to be escaped with a `\` backslash:

- `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `.`, `^`, `$`, `|` and `\`.

So if your requirements were alphanumeric characters and `_-=@,.;`, then the regex would be:

```
// alphanumeric and _-=@,.;
static final validCharacters = RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-=@,\.;]+$');
```

The `-` and the `.` were escaped.

## 2. Test a string

```
validCharacters.hasMatch('abc123');  // true
validCharacters.hasMatch('abc 123'); // false (spaces not allowed)
```

#### Try it yourself in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)

```
void main() {
  final validCharacters = RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-=@,\.;]+$');
  print(validCharacters.hasMatch('abc123'));
}
```

Comment: How I can check if strings contain all spaces or special characters and invalidate them with regEx?

Comment: @Aks, Without having tried it myself, you might be able to create a set of invalid characters with something like `[^abc]`. Then if `hasMatch` returns true you would know that everything is an invalid character. Another option is to loop through each character.

Comment: how about this character ' @Suragch

Comment: @little_Friend, You could use double quotes instead of single quotes if you're not also trying to match double quotes. Otherwise you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58143313/3681880).

Comment: Will it work for string containing emojis

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig, If you are trying to exclude emojis, then yes, the answer here works. For example, `'abc123'` returns `false`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regular expression to check if the string is alphanumeric.

```
class FormFieldValidator {
  static String validate(String value, String message) {
    return RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$").hasMatch(value) ? null : message;
  }
}
```