# escape " regexp in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to catch symbols in a dart Regexp. My regexp looks like this:

```
  RegExp containsSymbolRegExp = RegExp(r"[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:;'<>?,.\/]");
```

However, I also need to make it catch the symbol "
I can't stick " in there though, since it messes with the string. Any ideas how to do this?
Thanks.

edit: jamesdlin's answer works great for dart. But it doesn't work for my flutter app, so I'm thinking it has something to do with flutter. Here's the code I'm applying this to:

```
TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
bool containsSymbol;

RegExp containsSymbolRegExp = RegExp(r"[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}#@\[\]:;'<>?,.\/"
      '"'
      "]");

void _handleChange(text) {
    setState(() {
        containsSymbol = containsSymbolRegExp.hasMatch(_passwordController.text);
    });
    print(containsSymbol); // always prints false for " ' \ but works for all other symbols
  }

Widget _textField(controller, labelText) {
  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(labelText, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        height: 35,
        child: TextField(
          onChanged: _handleChange,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          controller: _passwordController,
          cursorColor: Colors.grey,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Usually you should ask a separate question instead of editing it into an existing question.  As for your new question: there's no reason why it shouldn't work in Flutter.  Are you sure that a straight quote is entered and not, say, "smart" curly quotes?

Comment: I see. Sorry, thanks. After testing, I'm almost certain it's because my text input is a "smart" curly quote. Knowing this, is there a way to restrict the textfield input or something? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to restrict input to, say, alphanumeric characters, then you should specify what characters you allow instead of which you disallow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could take advantage of string concatenation of adjacent string literals and either use a single-quoted string or use a non-raw string with `"` escaped:

```dart
RegExp(
  r"[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:;'<>?,.\/"
  '"'
  "]");
```

Alternatively you always could use a non-raw string with more escapes:

```dart
RegExp(
  "[-!\$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\\[\\]:;'<>?,.\\/\"]");
```

although that's messier.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't work  for me :(

Comment: @wei What happened when you tried it?  It works for me: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/78c388a2cf55bce610c8fd31c94d0058

Comment: Hm, it works on dartpad great but when I use the Regexp in conjunction with my Flutter app and textEditingController, it still doesn't show a match for the " character. Maybe it is something to do with the textEditingController. I will investigate further, thanks again for the help!

Comment: I edited my main question to be more specific, if you would like to take a look at it

Comment: The concatenation method worked for me. However, the I couldn't escape `"` with `\"` :(

Comment: @ValentinVIGNAL Without seeing exactly what you did when trying to escape, I can't help you.  Escaping using the exact code I gave in my answer works in DartPad.

Answer (score 7):

Better solution is to use triple `"` for string starting and ending.

In such case one `"` will not end the string.

Try this:

```
RegExp containsSymbolRegExp = RegExp(r"""your_regexp_here""");
```

Can also be done with apostrophes like this:

```
RegExp containsSymbolRegExp = RegExp(r'''your_regexp_here''');
```

Comment: the triple """ helps a lot in this case.

Comment: In case this still doesn't work, it is likely due to the Smart Punctuation feature in ios. Refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70737696/how-to-disable-smart-punctuation-in-flutter-textfield-problem-when-a-string-co)

Answer (score 4):

To answer to the edited part of your question being that it worked in Dart but not in Flutter...

It is because apostrophes/quotation marks from TextField values in Flutter are right quotation marks and therefore come in different Unicode.

For apostrophes, it's U+2019 (`’`) instead of U+0027 (`'`)

For quotation marks, U+201D (`”`) instead of U+0022 (`"`)

The Regex you were trying with is not capturing for such characters. Therefore, you just need to add those into your Regex.

```dart
RegExp containsSymbolRegExp = RegExp(
   r"[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}#@\[\]:;'’<>?,.\/"
   '"”'
   "]");
```

Tip: Debug! :)
I can already see some part of the value looking funny the moment it hits the breakpoint of where the value was about to be evaluated.

Comment: been searching for a solution for days! Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

To be a little more complete,

```dart
RegExp containsSymbolRegExp = RegExp(
  r'[!@#$%^&*()~`[=+-_\]/,.?":;{}|<>'
  '≥÷≤∞¢£™¡¶•ªº≠‘“∂ƒ©∆˚¬…æ√∫˜µ≈çœ∑´®†¥¨ˆø–π”’'
  "']",
);
```