# How to match special character like ` ," ,[] in flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, special-characters

When using Special Character in Regex,
I faced some problem.
In some special characters, `', ",[]`
the `\\(special character)` is not working.
When I logged case by case, the special character was problem.
Is there any one who know about this?
My regex is below

```
  // ' " cannot insert this characters

  RegExp specialCharReg= RegExp(r'[~!@#$%^&*()_+`{}|<>?;:./,=\-[]]');

  RegExp passwordReg = RegExp(
      r'^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[~!@#$%^&*()_+`{}|<>?;:./,=\-[]])[a-zA-Z\d~!@#$%^&*()_+`{}|<>?;:./,=\-[]]{8,20}$');

input : ghktkl12! , ghktkl12] 
both are not working in specialCharReg, because of [] in regexp
```

Comment: Both `specialCharReg` and `passwordReg` neglect to escape `[` and `]`.  Consequently `specialCharReg` tries to match one of those punctuation characters followed by a literal `]`.  It should be ```RegExp(r'[~!@#$%^&*()_+`{}|<>?;:./,=\-\[\]]')```.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I faced another problem. I prefixed `'`, `"`, ] with `\\`, and the ' or " doesn't work when I use r"^~~", or r'^~~', How can I use that two character together?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. "Doesn't work" isn't helpful.  What happens?  Do you mean that `RegExp(r'^~~')` doesn't match some input string as expected?  If so, what is your input string? `print(RegExp(r'^~~').hasMatch('~~hello'));` prints `true` for me.

Comment: not that mean. I wanna use `RegExp(r'\'');` this regex for the character `'`, but it doesn't work for `\'`.

Comment: `r'\''` will not work because the `r` prefix means it's a *raw* string that will not use string escape characters.  See [escape " regexp in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58141263/). (And what does that have to do with `r'^~~'`?)

Comment: thank you for answer, and the r'^~~' means r'^ some regex(bla bla == ~~)', it doesn't have any special mean.