# How to do multiple validations on TextFormField in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to perform multiple validations in TextFormField in flutter like field required validation, only alphabets validations or only numbers validation etc at the same time. Please suggest any idea. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help you  [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52835450/flutter-how-to-avoid-special-characters-in-validator)

Comment: i am asking about multiple validations, like 2 or more validations in textformfield. i have created 2 methods for validations. one for field required and other for checking that inputs should be only alphabets. i want to perform these 2 validation on textFormField at the same time.

Answer (score 7):

Package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder support build in validators
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder#built-in-validators
such as 
FormBuilderValidators.required() - requires the field have a non-empty value. 
FormBuilderValidators.numeric() - requires the field's value to be a valid number.

you can put two or more validate in validators attributes, 
code snippet

```
FormBuilderTextField(
  attribute: "age",
  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Age"),
  validators: [
    FormBuilderValidators.numeric(errorText: "La edad debe ser numérica."),
    FormBuilderValidators.max(70),
  ],
),
```

example code https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

working demo

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much. I got my answer i was looking for.

Comment: Hi, i couldn't use the commands you writed. some of them out dated i suppose? look like attribute became name.